# How would the earth spinning in reverse affect cultural development?

Tags: planets, earth, orbital-mechanics, science-in-society

How would the earth spinning in reverse affect cultural development?

I am interested in answers on tribes, religion and technology.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Please take the tour and visit the help center to learn more about the site if you have a moment. I am no expert on this topic, but this looks like it is too broad for the site. Could you try to narrow this down? What effects are you especially interested in and what did your research and ideas tell you so far about what might be different? Have fun on the site!

Comment: Not much; ask an Australian. Weather patterns will change. But nothing else to the solar system. Now if you put the world in a reverse spin in an instance, that would be chaos.

Comment: The Sun will rise in the West and set in the East. Which for the parallel Earth will be absolutely normal. Weather patterns might be different, but I'm not a meteorologist. Otherwise no difference.

Comment: Welcome to the site, KingLouie. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE prefers specific questions about a problem you are having with your world. Questions along the lines of, "I've made a change to Earth. What happens?" are almost always too broad to be addressed appropriately and reasonably in the SE format. If you could narrow this down to a specific aspect of your world you need/want help with, the community would appreciate it. Otherwise, this may be put on hold until such clarification is provided. If you haven't already, I would suggest taking the [tour] as well.

Comment: I feel like this has been asked before...anyone find it?

Comment: Louie can you narrow it down to one specific aspect?  For example you mention religion.  If you just ask about religion you may be specific enough to keep this from being too broad.

Comment: Also, check out the [help] when you have some time.  It give good guidance on writing good questions and answers.  (Getting used to the rules on the site takes a little time)

Comment: @Molot (among others) Actually not "too broad", because the answer is "not at all".

Comment: Maybe SE should also add the ability to bar comments based on broadness. Eh @Spencer?

Comment: If I thought I could provide a convincing "no" answer if it were reopened?

Answer (score 3):

**The main change would be the [Coriolis effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force)**.

The atmosphere isn't rigidly fixed to the solid ground so, in relation to the ground, the air seems to move. This is the root of all sorts of weather phenomenon. As [the MET office says:](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/learning/learn-about-the-weather/how-weather-works/coriolis-effect)

> This deflection is a major factor in explaining why winds blow anticlockwise around low pressure and clockwise around high pressure in the northern hemisphere and visa versa in the southern hemisphere.

These would be reversed if the spin was in the opposite direction. **The southern hemisphere does have its spin in the opposite direction** so we can see that the changes wouldn't be quite so drastic.

**The magnetic field would also be flipped** for the same reason, the molten metal flowing around causes a flow of charge which induces the magnetic field. I'm not sure this would change much though.

*I am assuming you're flipping everything, so the moon goes around us the other way we orbit the sun the other way, etc...if not the tides would play up and the day would be shorter.*

Comment: I'm glad to see someone knew what would happen. Well played, this man. Plus one for a nifty answer.

Comment: Awesome answer. I suppose flipping everything might be easier to describe too

Comment: It's not required for the moon to orbit in the reversed direction though, although it's formation may have occurred differently. Wouldn't tidal effects would be very much the same, since they are symmetric around the earth-moon axis?

Comment: @Innovine I thought so too for a bit but then if you think about the relative speeds (so how long the moon is above a bit of water for) then if the moon is orbiting in the same direction you get a smaller difference than if the moon is orbiting the opposite direction. I feel like it needs a picture to explain properly but hopefully that made some sense as to why it makes a difference.

Comment: @lio elbammalf hmm. I'm not sure to be honest. the effect you mention seems to me to only produce a slight asymmetry in the cycle, but I can't figure out if it would cause the spring and neap tides to slide out of sync in some way.. probably worth a question on space SE :)

Comment: @lio elbammalf when you add the planet/moons elasticity into this, you are now messing with the forces involved in keeping th moon tidally locked to us, with the same side always showing. I wonder if th effect you mention would be big enough to impact that

Comment: @Innovine I haven't plugged any numbers in to know the exact effects, it was more of an instinct than anything else.